# Submit form without reload page,using jquery ajax and grails

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

How i can update table without reload a page using ajax and Jquery.
I receive data from form.
My code below.

I used e.preventDefault(); 
But i saw new row in table only after i reloaded page myself.

```
 def allSkills(){
    User user = springSecurityService.currentUser
    List<Skill> skills = Skill.findAllByUser(user)
    ['skills':skills]
}


def addSkills(){
    User user = springSecurityService.currentUser
    Skill skill = new Skill(params)
    skill.setUser(user)
    skill.save()
    redirect(action: "allSkills")
}
```

and GSP

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="skillList">
                            <table class="table table-hover" id="table" >
                                <g:each in="${skills}" var="skill" >
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><h1 class="pull-left">${skill.skillName}</h1></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </g:each>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <hr style="margin: 5px 0 5px 0;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <g:form name="addSkillForm" id="addSkillForm" action="addSkills">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></span>
                                        <g:textField id="skillName" name="skillName" type="text"
                                                     class="form-Control" placeholder="Enter the name of skill"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <g:submitButton class="btn btn-info" id="submitAddSkill" name="submitAddSkill" value="Submit"/>
                            </g:form>

                        </div>
```

Comment: your question is about jquery ajax your code includes no ajax no jquery - unsure how you expect any answer

Comment: could you show your actual javascript